# get amount of lat and lon

Tags: android, kotlin, location, latitude-longitude

i got location and i have latitude and longitude in the method of getLocation and declared  local variable lat and lon in the class and default 0.0 when i pass that in to the api focast showed lat and lon 0.0   just show lat and lon in the method   out of method return 0.0

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val PERMISSION_ID = 42
    val CITY: String = "kalaleh"
    val API: String = "837f502858a52a78b98b5d7be51d0741"
    lateinit var mFusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
       var lat :Double = 0.0
       var lon:Double= 0.0



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)

        getLastLocation()


    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        weatherTask().execute()

    }



    private fun checkPermissions(): Boolean {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    private fun requestPermissions() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            arrayOf(
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ),
            PERMISSION_ID
        )
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_ID) {
            if ((grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                // Granted. Start getting the location information
            }
        }
    }

    private fun isLocationEnabled(): Boolean {
        var locationManager: LocationManager =
            getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
        return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) || locationManager.isProviderEnabled(
            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER
        )
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private fun getLastLocation() {
        if (checkPermissions()) {
            if (isLocationEnabled()) {

                mFusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                    var location: Location? = task.result
                    if (location == null) {
                        requestNewLocationData()
                    } else {
                      lat=location.latitude
                      lon=location.longitude

                        Log.i("getLOc","lat is : $lat")
                        Log.i("getLOc","lat is : $lon")

                    }
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Turn on location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        } else {
            requestPermissions()
        }

    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private fun requestNewLocationData() {
        var mLocationRequest = LocationRequest()
        mLocationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
        mLocationRequest.interval = 1000
        mLocationRequest.fastestInterval = 5000
        mLocationRequest.numUpdates = 1

        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
        mFusedLocationClient!!.requestLocationUpdates(
            mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback,
            Looper.myLooper()
        )
    }

    private val mLocationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
        override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
            var mLastLocation: Location = locationResult.lastLocation
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.latTextView).text = mLastLocation.latitude.toString()
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.lonTextView).text = mLastLocation.longitude.toString()
            lat=mLastLocation.latitude
            lon=mLastLocation.longitude




        }
    }

    inner class weatherTask() : AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {
        override fun onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute()
            /* Showing the ProgressBar, Making the main design GONE */
            findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.loader).visibility = View.VISIBLE
            findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.mainContainer).visibility = View.GONE
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.errorText).visibility = View.GONE
        }

        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: String?): String? {
            var response: String?
            try {
                Log.i("doINb","lat is : $lat")
                Log.i("doINb","lon is : $lon")


                response = URL("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=$lat&lon=$lon&units=metric&appid=$API").readText(
                    Charsets.UTF_8
                )
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                response = null
            }
            return response
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {
            super.onPostExecute(result)
            try {
                /* Extracting JSON returns from the API */
                val jsonObj = JSONObject(result)
                val main = jsonObj.getJSONObject("main")
                val sys = jsonObj.getJSONObject("sys")
                val wind = jsonObj.getJSONObject("wind")
                val weather = jsonObj.getJSONArray("weather").getJSONObject(0)

                val updatedAt: Long = jsonObj.getLong("dt")
                val updatedAtText =
                    "Updated at: " + SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH).format(
                        Date(updatedAt * 1000)
                    )
                val temp = main.getString("temp") + "°C"
                val tempMin = "Min Temp: " + main.getString("temp_min") + "°C"
                val tempMax = "Max Temp: " + main.getString("temp_max") + "°C"
                val pressure = main.getString("pressure")
                val humidity = main.getString("humidity")

                val sunrise: Long = sys.getLong("sunrise")
                val sunset: Long = sys.getLong("sunset")
                val windSpeed = wind.getString("speed")
                val weatherDescription = weather.getString("description")

                val address = jsonObj.getString("name") + ", " + sys.getString("country")

                /* Populating extracted data into our views */
                findViewById<TextView>(R.id.address).text = address
                findViewById<TextView>(R.id.updated_at).text = updatedAtText
                findViewById<TextView>(R.id.status).text = weatherDescription.capitalize()
                findViewById<TextView>(R.id.temp).text = temp
                findViewById<TextView>(R.id.temp_min).text = tempMin
                findViewById<TextView>(R.id.temp_max).text = tempMax
                findViewById<TextView>(R.id.sunrise).text =
                    SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH).format(Date(sunrise * 1000))
                findViewById<TextView>(R.id.sunset).text =
                    SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH).format(Date(sunset * 1000))
                findViewById<TextView>(R.id.wind).text = windSpeed
                findViewById<TextView>(R.id.pressure).text = pressure
                findViewById<TextView>(R.id.humidity).text = humidity

                /* Views populated, Hiding the loader, Showing the main design */
                findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.loader).visibility = View.GONE
                findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.mainContainer).visibility = View.VISIBLE

            } catch (e: Exception) {
                findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.loader).visibility = View.GONE
                findViewById<TextView>(R.id.errorText).visibility = View.VISIBLE

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any `getLocation` method. Did you mean `getLastLocation`? In any case, why are you starting the `weatherTask` in `onStart`, instead of waiting until you've actually received a location?

Comment: sorry yes i mean getlastLocation i pot weatherTask.execuete onCreat  method but still didnt work  lat and lon return 0.0 just return decimal number inside of getlastlocation  outside of of getlastlocation return 0.0 @Michael

Answer (score 1):

In `getLastLocation()`, you added an `onCompleteListener` to the last location. You try to get an initial value of `lat` `lon` through last location, then get continuous return as location updates.

You might assume `task.result` to be `null` at first, then `requestNewLocationData()` would be called. Instead you see the log output. That means it gives you a one-time output of 0.0, 0.0, which is the default value if there is no last known location.

You should call `requestNewLocationData()` no matter task.result is null or not.